An analytic function on from the open disk to itself with at least two fixed points is the identity
I know that the general strategy is to use an automorphism totransform your function into one that is 0 at the origin and then apply Schwarz' Lemma, however I'm a bit lost as to how you apply Schwarz Lemma here -- all the other solutions on stack exchange simply say this bit is "obvious."
If $f$ is an automorphism of the disk with $f(0)=0$ then we know $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ but I don't see how this says anything about the fixed points. The fixed points certainly satisfy this inequality since $|f(z)|=|z|$ when $z$ is a fixed point, but I'm not really sure what to do with that information.
I feel like I have to be missing something obvious. Can someone help?

The identity has much more than one fixed point. Are you missing an assumption?

Yes, sorry, that was a mistake. You need to show that given $f$ has more than one fixed point then it must be the identity.

The full Schwarz lemma says that if in addition we have a $z_0\neq 0$ in the unit ball such that $\vert f(z_0) \vert = \vert z_0 \vert$, then there exists $a\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\vert a \vert=1$ such that $f(z)=az$. This easily implies the claim.

Luckily a cheese doctor has stopped in and marked this a duplicate.

@youthinasia What is your point?

@SeverinSchraven ah, well that explains why I was finding the question difficult... thank you!

@Vibbz You are very welcome. Indeed, if you have not seen that before, it's not that easy.

I guess just that it's good to have people about as successful as a Justin Bieber say to help organize things.
